# Bootstrap 5: What I need to do to have a search icon in navbar that when I click it, it will show a search box under the navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

[This is what I have done so far for the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixcWT.png)

I need to put a search icon beside log in button. When I click the search icon, a search box will appear under the navbar that look something like in the picture below. My navbar is transparent, position is relative and the header beneath is a video loop with autoplay, position is relative.

[Taken from DataCamp website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT8vk.png)

I have tried free templates codes from other sites but it will give weird results when combined with my existing code and I have tried to change the template codes, still negative results. If possible I want to minimize the usage of js and css so that I can tweak the look easily without hassling too much. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to position the search box under the navbar. Then add a class that will make it visible and add and event listener to the button that toggles that class on and off.

See snippet below

```js
document.querySelector(`#btn-search`).addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  document.querySelector(`#search`).classList.toggle(`show-search`);
});
```

```css
#search {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  position: absolute;
}

.show-search {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha512-siwe/oXMhSjGCwLn+scraPOWrJxHlUgMBMZXdPe2Tnk3I0x3ESCoLz7WZ5NTH6SZrywMY+PB1cjyqJ5jAluCOg==' crossorigin='anonymous' />

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-dark py-3 position-relative">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">First Item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="d-block">
      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control position-absolute shadow-sm" placeholder="Search">
      <a class="btn btn-light me-2" role="button" id="btn-search" href="#"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#">Login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You could also use the off-canvas component baked into bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/

See off canvas snippet below

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha512-siwe/oXMhSjGCwLn+scraPOWrJxHlUgMBMZXdPe2Tnk3I0x3ESCoLz7WZ5NTH6SZrywMY+PB1cjyqJ5jAluCOg==' crossorigin='anonymous' />

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-dark py-3 position-relative">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">First Item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="d-block">
      <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight"></button>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#">Login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasRightLabel">Offcanvas right</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control shadow-sm" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' integrity='sha512-1TK4hjCY5+E9H3r5+05bEGbKGyK506WaDPfPe1s/ihwRjr6OtL43zJLzOFQ+/zciONEd+sp7LwrfOCnyukPSsg==' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! At first, I used the first code you suggested and changed the display from none to block. After a few thoughts, I changed my mind to use the second method which is the offcanvas. I changed it to offcanvas-top instead of right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag `shouldShowSearchInput`. By default, it should be false.

You can use it to change `display` of `Search Input Element` to be `none` or `block`

When you click `SearchIcon` changes the value of that flag.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Help me to try it in different angle.